# Then the number of pairs $(A,B)$ ,where $A,B$ are non-empty disjoint subsets of $S$ is

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification, permutations, combinations

Let $S=\{1,2,3...10\} $ .Then the number of pairs $(A,B)$ ,where $A,B$ are non-empty disjoint subsets of $S$ is

(1) $3^{10}-1$

(2)$3^{10}-2^{10}$

(3)$3^{10}-2^{10}+1$

(4)$3^{10}-2^{11}+1$

I think the answer is (1) $3^{10}-1$ .

My reasoning : 
There are $ {10} \choose {k} $subsets of size $k$ . We assign one $k$-subset to $A$ and observe that $B$ can be subset of $S-A$ . Now $|S-A|=10-k$ . So number of possible disjoint subset must be $2^{10-k} $

So number of ways choosing pair of subsets $(A,B)$ when $|A|=k$ is = $ { {10} \choose {k}} 2^{10-k}$ .

Now we sum this expression from $k=1 $ to $10$ .We choose to start from $k=1$ as  $A$ must not be non-empty .

So by binomial theorem : $\sum_{k=1}^{10}  { {10} \choose {k}} 2^{10-k}=3^{10}-1$ .

Is my reasoning correct ?

I would also like to find out the answer when $|S|=n$  .

Thank you .

Comment: But $B$ must be non-empty, so number of allowable pairs with $|A|=k$ is ${10\choose k}(2^{10-k}-1)$.

Comment: @ Lord Shark : Yes of course ! I shouldn't have missed that . So the answer is $3^{10} -2^{10} $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the binomial theorem seems like overkill here. It seems like it would be easier to think about this in terms of words: we can encode such a pair as a word of length 10 over the alphabet 'a', 'b', 'n', where the $i$th character encodes whether the number $i$ lies in $A$, $B$, or neither set. It's easy to count the total number of words over this alphabet, so the question boils down to: how many words are forbidden by the nonemptiness requirement?

(Also, I think a good strategy for checking your answer here is to try setting $n=2$ and seeing what answer your approach would give there.)